# How to draw a square using WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

I was trying to draw a simple square based on the book  **WebGL Beginner's  guid**  by **Diego Cantor & Brandon Jones** but got stuck in lesson two.

I was trying to draw a square but my console shows error message as follows:

```
WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawArrays: attribs not setup correctly
```

What i tried is given below:

**My Code sample**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WebGL-Lesson One</title>
<style type="text/css">
canvas {
    border: 2px dotted black;
}
</style>
<script id="code-js" type="text/javascript">
    var gl = null;

    function getGlContext() {
        var my_canvas = document.getElementById("my_canvas");
        var names = [ "webgl", "experimental-webgl", "webkit-3d", "moz-webgl" ];
        for ( var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
            try {
                gl = my_canvas.getContext(names[i]);
            } catch (e) {
            }
            if (gl)
                break;
        }
        if (gl == null) {
            alert("empty canvas")
        } else {
            drawing();
        }
    }

    function drawing() {
        var vertices = [ -50.0, 50.0, 0.0, -50.0, -50.0, 0.0, 50.0, -50.0, 0.0,
                50.0, 50.0, 0.0 ];
        var indices = [ 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0 ]

        var myVBOBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, myVBOBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices),
                gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        var aVertexPosition = (0,0,0);

        gl.vertexAttribPointer(aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aVertexPosition);

        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    //  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

        var myIBOBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, myIBOBuffer);

        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    //  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);


    }
</script>
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/xfragment"></script>
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getGlContext()">

    <canvas id="my_canvas" width="700" height="500"></canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a middleware library instead? I've enjoyed toying with pixi.js, its a webGL rendering library with canvas fallback.If you're aiming to build a game engine this might be something to consider, and it handles all the boilerplate work. So less time getting it to work and more time actually working.

Comment: +1 @tsturzl I am just started learn this thing.., not that much aware of *.js frameworks. But, as you said intention is to create some good web application (game itself :) :D ). thanks anyway.

Comment: I'd recommend [these lessons](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-fundamentals/). They start at a much more basic level than other lessons and will help you really understand what is happening.

Comment: @gman : when I try as in this lesson you provided, got  ERROR : Uncaught ReferenceError: createShaderFromScriptElement is not defined

Comment: You're saying [this page](http://games.greggman.com/downloads/examples/webgl/webgl-2d-rectangle.html) gives you an error? Or are you saying you downloaded the page and tried to run it locally and it gave you an error? You need [this script](http://games.greggman.com/downloads/examples/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js) copied locally to run it locally. [This article explains that script](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-boilerplate/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shader scripts appear to be empty. You need at the very least a basic vertex and fragment shader. You also need to load, compile them and create the shader programs, and then you need to call gl.useProgram to set up your attribs, get uniform locations, and set uniform values. I recommend trying [these lessons](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217), they worked for me.